# Hibernate multi-module project: extend entity to add many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, entity-relationship, multi-module

I have a project that uses Hibernate and is divided into multiple modules.
I have the following modules:

- device (defines entity `Device`)
- appstore (defines entity `Application`)
- device-appstore-integration (adds many-to-many relationship between `Device` and `Application`).

Entities look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
public class Device extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable
{
    @NotNull
    @EmbeddedId
    private DeviceIdentity identity;

    // ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "apps")
public class App extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // ...
}
```

Now I want `device-appstore-integration` module to add many-to-many relationship between the two entities above.
I thought about adding entity `DeviceWithInstalledApps` to define this many2many relationship and used the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
public class DeviceWithInstalledApps extends Device
{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "devices_installed_apps",
            joinColumns = {/*...*/},
            inverseJoinColumns = {/*...*/}
    )
    private Set<App> installedApps = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate requires `devices` table to include `dtype` column and treats `DeviceWithInstalledApps` as a separate entity that inherits from `Device` but I don't actually want it to be a separate entity. It's still the same entity, just with many-to-many relationship added so that I can actually access this relationship, no columns are added so there is no actual need to provide `dtype` column, it simply doesn't make sense in this context.

Is there any other way to define many-to-many relationship in JPA/Hibernate so that I can actually implement business logic without getting into issues mentioned above?